# How to group or factor out exponential terms under complex i paranthesis

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching

I am not able to group the terms of the below two Gaussian exponentials according to e^(const*(r1^2+r2^2))+e^(const* I*(r1^2-r2^2))+e^(const*(r1-r2)^2). Note that (r1^2-r2^2) paranthesis has complex I in front of it.

```
expr1 = Exp[(-I*k*A)/(2*B)*(r1^2-r2^2)-k^2/(4*p^2*B^2)*r1^2 + 
1/(4*p^2)*(I*a*r1-I*b*r2)^2]
```

which is actually the result of the following integral, everything is a constant except r1,r2

```
expr2 = Integrate[
E^(-((a*ρ1^2 + b*ρ2^2)/(4*σ^2)))*
E^(-((ρ2 - ρ1)^2/(2*δij^2)))*
E^((-I*k)/(2*B)*(A*(ρ1^2 - ρ2^2) - 
2*(r1*ρ1 - r2*ρ2) + 
F*(r1^2 - r2^2))), {ρ1, -Infinity, 
Infinity}, {ρ2, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
GenerateConditions -> False]
```

I've tried Collect, Factor, FactorTerms, doThat, Simplify...etc. which didnt work. They do it like in the image

[image]

I dont even know how to group like that by hand. So I am trying to do it by Mathematica.

Comment: `Expand[expr1 /. Exp[z_] :> z 
  ] // ComplexExpand ` gives the exponent in the  form `(...)+I(...)`

Comment: It didnt do it :(  so how do I obtain all three exponential groupings

Comment: The expression from my comment gives `-((a^2 r1^2)/(4 p^2)) - (k^2 r1^2)/(4 B^2 p^2) + (a b r1 r2)/(
 2 p^2) - (b^2 r2^2)/(4 p^2) + 
 I (-((A k r1^2)/(2 B)) + (A k r2^2)/(2 B))`

Comment: Yes I know, I am still trying to get the remaining  two exponentials. Thanks a lot by the way.